# perl code to Concatenate value of a column if other column value is same

Tags: perl

I want to write perl code to concatenate value of a column2 if other column value1 is same.  My input is tab delimited and contains 3 cloumns.

Input file:

```
Date                 Server        application
01/02/2013 00:00     abc123        perl_module_1
01/02/2013 00:00     abc123        oracle_patch_201
03/05/2014 00:00     abc123        Microsoft_patch_71
04/04/2015 00:00     xyz1          oracle_patch_201
02/12/2015 00:00     xyz1          Cygwin_app
```

Output:

```
abc123 = ("perl_module_1","oracle_patch_201","Microsoft_patch_71")
xyz1 = ("oracle_patch_201","Cygwin_app")
```

My code is as below.  As you can see it is not good enough

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'oneplatformserver.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "could not open $file: $!";
my $application_string="";
my $date_string="";

while (my $line= <$info>) 
{

 chomp $line;
 my @values = split('\t', $line);

    my $application= $values[2];
   # $application =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; # This command will trim spaces at the end of the line
    my $Quoteapplication = '"'.$application.'"';
    my $QuoteDate = '"'.$oracledate.'"';

    $application_string = join(',',$application_string,$Quoteapplication);

    $date_string = join(',',$date_string,$QuoteDate);
    print "Date_String is $date_string \n";
    printf("UPA \"TSTCM2:%s.A;1\" /ATTRIBUTES=(application_ID=[ %s ],APPLIED_DATE=[ %s ])", $server,$application_string,$date_string);  

 }
close $info;

# printf("UPB \"QAS:%s.A;1\" /ATTRIBUTES=(application_ID=[ %s ],APPLIED_DATE=[ %s ])", $server,$applicationstring,$datestring);
```

Comment: Can you describe what is wrong with your code?

Comment: Do you want to play golf?

Answer (score 2):

As you are talking about key value pairs, the answer is 'use a hash'.

```
my %applications_on;

while ( <$info> ) {
   chomp;
   my ( $date, $time, $server, $application ) = split; 
   push ( @{ $applications_on{$server} }, $application );
}

foreach my $server ( keys %applications_on ) {
    print "($server) = ".join ( ",", @{ $applications_on{$server} } ); 
}
```

Something like that, at any rate.

Comment: Many Thanks Sobrique.  I tried your code and was able the get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

my $fname = 'data.txt';

open my $INFILE, '<', $fname
    or die "Couldn't open $fname: $!";

my $header = <$INFILE>;
say "0123456789" x 7;
say $header;

my %apps_for;

while (my $line = <$INFILE>) {
    my ($server, $app) = unpack '@21 A14 A*', $line;  #see explanation below

    my $trailing_whitespace = qr{\s* \z}xms;
    $server =~ s/$trailing_whitespace//;
    $app =~ s/$trailing_whitespace//;

    push @{$apps_for{$server}}, $app;
}

close $INFILE;
say Dumper(\%apps_for);

for my $server (keys %apps_for) {
    say "$server:";
    say "  $_" for @{$apps_for{$server}};
}


--output:--
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
Date                 Server        application

$VAR1 = {
          'xyz1' => [
                      'oracle_patch_201',
                      'Cygwin_app'
                    ],
          'abc123' => [
                        'perl_module_1',
                        'oracle_patch_201',
                        'Microsoft_patch_71'
                      ]
        };

xyz1:
  oracle_patch_201
  Cygwin_app
abc123:
  perl_module_1
  oracle_patch_201
  Microsoft_patch_71
```

...

```
@21 A14 A*   @21 -> move to position 21
             A14 -> extract 14 characters(A)
             A*  -> extract the remaining(*) characters(A)
```

If you really want the exact output you showed:

```
for my $server (keys %apps_for) {
    local $" = ', ';
    say "$server = (@{$apps_for{$server}})";
}

--output:--
xyz1 = (oracle_patch_201, Cygwin_app)
abc123 = (perl_module_1, oracle_patch_201, Microsoft_patch_71)
```

> $"
>
> When an array or an array slice is interpolated into a double-quoted
>   string or a similar context such as /.../ , its elements are separated
>   by this value. Default is a space.
>   http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: Many Thanks 7stud.  Appreciate to not only help me but also to explain in detail.

Comment: @amma, You're welcome.  When you have values that are in fixed width columns, like your data, unpack() is the most efficient way to extract the values.